# PHP session variables lost in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

This is a real baffler. I have written a system in PHP saves session variables to show that a User has logged in successfully. I tested the system in every browser using MAMP and it worked fine. When I put the system live I put it into a subdirectory of my main domain. If I call my programs directly using the main domain/sub directory name in the URL the session variables are saved and the system works in every browser, HOWEVER I have a different domain pointing to the subdirectory and if I call my programs by entering the different domain name as the URL everything works for all browsers except Google Chrome...which doesn't save the session variables causing the User to be thrown back to the login screen repeatedly.

I'm certain my PHP is correct and there is nothing in my error log.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I think I could get round the problem by using cookies instead but I'd like to know what the problem is.

Comment: You need to show us your code of the login, and when you check the session.

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('Connections/umm.php');
// check whether user should be in here
if($_SESSION['allow'] == false || !isset($_SESSION['allow']) || ($_SESSION['authority'] < 1) || ($_SESSION['authority'] > 2)) {
 header("location: index.php"); 
 } else { ?>

Comment: The files are in a subdirectory. When I enter domain/subdirectory the variables are saved. When I point an external domain to the same subdirectory and enter externaldomain/ the variables are not saved. This only happens in Chrome and does not happen when I access localhosting.